# Error when playing Media Files

Tags: android

I'm using MediaPlayer to play some sounds files, which at times overlap. I notice that in the LogCat window I keep getting this message:

android max instances of component OMX.TI.ACC. Decode already created.

It seems to have no effect on my application as the sounds continue to play just fine. Does anyone know what this message means, and do I need to worry about it?

Answer (score 0):

SoundPool may be a better option for playing multiple, short sounds.

**Creating SoundPool**

```
public static final int SOUND_1 = 1;
public static final int SOUND_2 = 2;

SoundPool mSoundPool;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> mHashMap;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    mSoundPool = new SoundPool(2, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 100);
    mSoundMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();

    if(mSoundPool != null){
        mSoundMap.put(SOUND_1, mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound1, 1));
        mSoundMap.put(SOUND_2, mSoundPool.load(this, R.raw.sound2, 1));
    }
}
```

Then play a sound by calling a custom function.

**Playing Sound**

```
/*
*Call this function from code with the sound you want e.g. playSound(SOUND_1);
*/
public void playSound(int sound) {
    AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    float streamVolumeCurrent = mgr.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float streamVolumeMax = mgr.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    float volume = streamVolumeCurrent / streamVolumeMax;  

    if(mSoundPool != null){
        mSoundPool.play(mSoundMap.get(sound), volume, volume, 1, 0, 1.0f);
    }
}
```